# Getting Contact ID from Android Contacts database is not working as intended

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-contacts

I have the following code.

```
        int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();

    Cursor contactLookupCursor =  context.getContentResolver().query( Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(contactNumber)), new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID},null,null,null);     

    try 
    {
        contactLookupCursor.moveToFirst();
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
         }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        contactLookupCursor.close();
    }
```

The problem in the above code is that even if I give a existing number in emulator contacts, its not returning any results. I was testing it an hour back and it was working fine, and now when I tested it again, its not returning anything. I am not sure if anything is wrong with the code. What I am trying to do is get a ID that matches a single with multiple numbers. For instance say there is a contact name called "A" and A has two numbers. Essentially the contact ID for A should be 1 regardless of which number I refer to. Is my assumption correct ?

UPDATE : I did some more tests. Let's say if a number is stored without the country code in the contacts database like 222-222-2222. A search using the below code returns contact id only when I pass 2222222222 or 222-222-2222. And if the same number is stored like 12222222222 a valid contact id is received only if I search number is 12222222222.

```
        String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID};
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(contactNumber));
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        phoneContactID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
    }
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
public static int getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber,Context context)
{
    contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
    int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
    Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,contactNumber),new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
        contactLookupCursor.close();

    return phoneContactID;
}
```

The code that is working now.

Comment: great +1 for my side.Really helpfull

Comment: some error, you have encode(contactNumber) twice, in some case, your result is null if the phone number in your device include the country code.

Comment: why you use "new Random().nextInt();"? in this case you should write -1 or change it to nullable Integer type.

Answer (score 3):

Ok..Sorry i miss interpreted your question
I had not done it.But i think follwing code might work
Give it a try and lemme know:

```
Cursor phone_cursor = cr.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?", 
                        new String[]{"YOUR NUMBER GOES HERE"}, null); 
                while (phone_cursor.moveToNext()) 
                { 

//here you can extract the inofrmation you want


phone_cursor.getString(             phone_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I tried the above code and it was not able to get any results back. However, whenever I formatted the input to match exactly like how it is stored in contacts, it returned an id for me. For instance 1-234-567-8900 gave me results but 2345678900 did not give me results.

Comment: Thank You for your efforts K-ran-Beast. For some reason my original code started working.

Comment: welcome vikram...pls also post your working snippets also if you find the answer yourself....thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Peform the steps in the follwing manner:

//This method will return a cursor which will contain whole info

```
private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,      
        };

        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
```

Next you can iterate through this Cursor to get the name and ID as Follows:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
            {
                namess[i]= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                id[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: Your code will help me iterate through the contacts. I want to query the contacts for a given number and extract the contact ID. I am not sure how this code helps me.

Answer (score 0):

vikramjb answer is great, I tried to do it in a clearer way (by using the instructions here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html):

```
private Long GetContactIdFromNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver, String number)
{
    Uri contactLookup = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    Cursor contactLookupCursor = contentResolver.query(contactLookup,new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
    if (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
        long ret = contactLookupCursor.getLong(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        contactLookupCursor.close();
        return ret;
    }
    contactLookupCursor.close();
    return 0l;
}
```

BTW, in api versions (above 21) there is the `PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID` column in `CallLog.Calls`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html