# android is CallLog.Calls._ID the same with the contact id?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I created a log call list. I want to add the picture to each contact in ann imageview. I would like to ask if

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, "DATE DESC");
int id = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID);

is the same with ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
```

If this two are not the same how can I obtain the contact is using managedCursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't. It is just the ID of the row.
Anyway you can read the phone number from the `NUMBER` field and obtain the contact id with this code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374721/321354

Comment: is there a way i can detect contact id from log id ?