# Looking for a common Contact ID between Telephony.Sms and CallLog.Calls

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts

**Goal:** I'm trying to group SMS and calls from same (known) contacts.

- I read SMS using `Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI` and `Telephone.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI`.
- I read calls using `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_UTI`.

I get the contact's ID by following [android is CallLog.Calls._ID the same with the contact id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778342/android-is-calllog-calls-id-the-same-with-the-contact-id): using `Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, phoneNumber)`.

Now, having this `PhoneLookup._ID`, I  want to list SMS from that contact.

Sadly `Telephony.Sms.PERSON` does not seem to store the same contact ID.

**Question:** How could I list SMS from that `PhoneLookup._ID` or if not possible, how could I achieve what I want: list SMS and calls from the same contact.

PS: `Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.PERSON` seems to refer the the deprecated `Contacts.People` API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Telephony.Sms.PERSON` actually matchs `ContactsContract.DataColumns.RAW_CONTACT_ID`.

So I used:

```
final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projection, selection, null, null);
```

Reading `ContactsContract.DataColumns.RAW_CONTACT_ID`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#RAW_CONTACT_ID